# Escape key press infinite loop in C

Tags: c, infinite-loop, ncurses

I am using curses library. I want my application to keep on executing till Escape key is pressed. It should not block for next key input,

My working code is: This waits for user input at key=getch(); I want this to be non-blocking till someone presses ESCAPE KEY.
It should not wait for keyboard input.

```
while (true)
{
    key=getch();
    if (key==ESCAPE)
    {
        break;
    }
    //else
    //{
        //execute something 
    //}
}//while end
```

Comment: Advice number 1, indent your code properly

Answer (score 2):

You can call the [`timeout`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/curs_inopts/) function like this before your loop:

```
timeout(0);
```

and then `getch` will not block anymore.

The description for the function is:

```
void timeout(int delay);
void wtimeout(WINDOW *win, int delay);
```

> The timeout and wtimeout routines set blocking or non-blocking read for
>   a  given  window.   If  delay is negative, blocking read is used (i.e.,
>   waits indefinitely for input).  If delay  is  zero,  then  non-blocking
>   read is used (i.e., read returns ERR if no input is waiting).  If delay
>   is positive, then read blocks for delay milliseconds, and  returns  ERR
>   if  there  is  still  no input.  Hence, these routines provide the same
>   functionality as nodelay, plus the additional capability of being  able
>   to block for only delay milliseconds (where delay is positive).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample:

```
#include <curses.h>

int
main (void)
{
  int c;

  initscr ();
  noecho ();
  timeout (0);

  while (1)
    {
      c = getch ();
      if (c != ERR)
      {
        printw ("%c", c);
      }
      if (c == 27)
      {
        break;
      }
    }

  echo ();
  endwin ();
  return 0;
}
```

The `timeout ()` function tells how long a blocking call should wait before return. A 0 value means non-blocking, and positive value `x` will wait `x` milliseconds before returning.

Here is the section from curses man page:

> The timeout and wtimeout routines set blocking or non-blocking read for a given window.  If delay is
>   negative, blocking read is used (i.e., waits indefinitely for input).  If delay is zero,  then  non-
>   blocking  read  is used (i.e., read returns ERR if no input is waiting).  If delay is positive, then
>   read blocks for delay milliseconds, and returns ERR if there is still no input.  Hence,  these  rou‐
>   tines  provide  the  same  functionality as nodelay, plus the additional capability of being able to
>   block for only delay milliseconds (where delay is positive).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by setting [no delay mode](http://linux.die.net/man/3/nodelay). Then `getch` will not block and return `ERR` when there is no key.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your responses. I resolved this using kbhit()